# Nav Link Function Failure

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason my nav links to their respective sections have stopped functioning on my portfolio template site. Is there a quick JavaScript or JQuery solution that I could put into my script section to give them function again?

Nav Anchor Tag Example

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#page-profile">Profile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Section Target Example

```
<section id="page-profile" class="page-profile">
        <div class="container">
            <header class="section-header">
                <h2 class="section-title">Personal Profile</h2>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <p class="section-subtitle">About Me</p>
            </header>
```

Comment: Post the code that was working.

Comment: There is too much code to post and I'm not sure what part of it could have ended functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$("moveToSectionButtonSelector").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#page-profile").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Is there a solution that would apply to multiple sections like #page-welcome, #page-education?

Comment: @springathing You mean you have multiple button for multiple section? You could add a `data-` attribute to your button which will contain your selector for the section you want to scroll to upon clicking it (make sure all your buttons have the same `class` which you will use with the `click` event). When clicked, check the `data-` attribute and assign it to some variable (like this: `var section = $(this).prop('data-whateverYouNameIt');`) then change `scrollTop: $("#page-profile").offset().top` to `scrollTop: $(section).offset().top`.

Comment: Cool, I ended up using your code and my nav links now work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
// URL Parsing
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = window.location.href;
var hash = parser.hash;

// Page scrolling
var offset = 20; //Offset of 20px

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top + offset
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with URL Parsing yet

Comment: What I used is a simple solution to parse a url quickly. This will allow you to direct someone to yourwebsite.com#page-profile and it will always take them to that section without needing to press a button each page visit. It will also work with your pre-existing code.